# Ошибка в Kivy: AttributeError

Tags: python, kivy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]введите сюда описание изображенияпишу программу, в которой нужно удалить виджет, но для этого мне как я понял нужно использовать функцию super(), но ошибка остается та же, вот кстати и она:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/Рабочий стол/Python/Paswording.py", line 1151, in <module>
PaswordingApp().run()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
runTouchApp()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
self._mainloop()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
EventLoop.idle()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
self.dispatch_input()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1402, in on_motion
self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1418, in on_touch_down
if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\popup.py", line 228, in on_touch_down
return super(Popup, self).on_touch_down(touch)
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\modalview.py", line 247, in on_touch_down
super(ModalView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
self.dispatch('on_press')
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
File "d:/Рабочий стол/Python/Paswording.py", line 964, in popup_active
self.delete.dismiss()
File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\uix\modalview.py", line 229, in dismiss
if self.dispatch('on_dismiss') is True:
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
File "d:/Рабочий стол/Python/Paswording.py", line 1007, in OnClose
exec(command)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "d:/Рабочий стол/Python/Paswording.py", line 930, in delette
self.layout.remove_widget(self.btn)
AttributeError: 'PopupClass' object has no attribute 'layout'
```

А вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.config import ConfigParser
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import (Color, Ellipse, Line)

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelHeader

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

import random
import ast
import os

# Создаем класс для окна с сохраненными кнопками:
class SavePaswords(Screen):

    # Создаем конструктор:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    # Создаем все layout'и и виджети, а потом добавляем виджети в layout'и:
    def on_enter(self):

        # layout'и:
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 5, size_hint_y = None, padding = [10])
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height = self.layout.setter('height'))
        self.boxlayoutpopup = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", spacing = 5, padding = [10]) 
        self.anchorlayoutpoputyes = AnchorLayout(anchor_x = "left", anchor_y = "bottom")
        self.anchorlayoutpoputnow = AnchorLayout(anchor_x = "right", anchor_y = "bottom")

        # Виджеты:
        labelwhat = Label(text = "Delete Pasword?")

        buttonyes = Button(text = "Yes", on_press = self.delette)
        buttonnow = Button(text = "Now", on_press = self.now)

        self.anchorlayoutpoputyes.add_widget(buttonyes)
        self.anchorlayoutpoputnow.add_widget(buttonnow)

        # Добавление виджетов:
        self.boxlayoutpopup.add_widget(labelwhat)
        self.boxlayoutpopup.add_widget(self.anchorlayoutpoputyes)
        self.boxlayoutpopup.add_widget(self.anchorlayoutpoputnow)

        # Кнопка возврата:
        back_button = Button(text = "Back",
                            background_color = [5, 1, 1, 5],
                            size_hint_y = None, height = dp(55),
                            on_press = self._back_to_the_mainscreen)
    
        # Метка для обозначения что здесь хранятся кнопки:
        label_paswords = Label(text = "Paswords:", font_size = 25, size_hint_y = None, height = dp(30))

        # Добавляем виджети:
        self.layout.add_widget(back_button)
        self.layout.add_widget(label_paswords)

        # Создаем прокрутку:
        root = RecycleView(size_hint = (1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))

        root.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.add_widget(root)

        dic_foods = ast.literal_eval(
            App.get_running_app().config.get("Paswords", 'pasword_data'))

        # Создаем цикл для создания кнопок:
        for f, d in sorted(dic_foods.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]):
            fd = f.decode('u8') + ' - ' + (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            self.btn = Button(text = fd, size_hint_y = None, height = dp(70), on_press = self.delete_pasword)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)

    def on_leave(self):
        self.layout.clear_widgets()

    # Создаем диалоговое окно:
    def delete_pasword(self, arg):
        dlg = PopupClass(titleheader = "Remove", message = "Delete Pasword?", options = {"YES": "delete_func()", "NO": "now()"})

    # Здесь посути должны удалятся кнопки, но вылезает ошибка:
    def delete_func(self):
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.btn)

    # Функция для закрытия диалогового окна:
    def now(self):
        pass

    # Функция для возврата в главное меню:
    def _back_to_the_mainscreen(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "main_screen"



# Создаем класс для диалогового окна:
class PopupClass(SavePaswords):

    # Конструктор:
    def __init__(self, titleheader = "Title", message = "Message", options = {"OK": "self.ok()", "NO": "self.no()"}):

        # Здесь ошибка:
        super(SavePaswords).__init__()

        def popup_active(event):
            self.retvalue = event.text
            self.delete.dismiss()

        self.retvalue = None
        self.options = options
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.box.add_widget(Label(text = message, font_size = 20))
        b_list = []
        buttonbox = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')

        for b in options:
            b_list.append(Button(text = b, size_hint = (1,.35), font_size = 20))
            b_list[-1].bind(on_press = popup_active)
            buttonbox.add_widget(b_list[-1])

        self.box.add_widget(buttonbox)
        self.delete = Popup(title = titleheader, content = self.box, size_hint=(None, None), size = (300, 300))
        self.delete.open()
        self.delete.bind(on_dismiss = self.on_close)

    def on_close(self, event):
        self.delete.unbind(on_dismiss = self.on_close)
        self.delete.dismiss()

        if self.retvalue != None:
            command = "super(PopupClass, self)." + self.options[self.retvalue]
            exec(command)
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111563/discussion-between-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica-and-arteman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ДИСКЛЕЙМЕР***: Адский говнокод, недописано, но идею вы уловили. Лучше помочь не могу, ваш код мне плохо понятен.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.config import ConfigParser
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import (Color, Ellipse, Line)

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelHeader

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

import random
import ast
import os
# Создаем класс для окна с сохраненными кнопками:
class SavePaswords(Screen):

    # Создаем конструктор:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # layout'и:
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=5, size_hint_y=None, padding=[10])
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
        self.boxlayoutpopup = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", spacing=5, padding=[10])
        self.anchorlayoutpoputyes = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="left", anchor_y="bottom")
        self.anchorlayoutpoputnow = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="right", anchor_y="bottom")

        # Виджеты:
        labelwhat = Label(text="Delete Pasword?")

        buttonyes = Button(text="Yes", on_press=self.delete_func)
        buttonnow = Button(text="Now", on_press=self.now)

        self.anchorlayoutpoputyes.add_widget(buttonyes)
        self.anchorlayoutpoputnow.add_widget(buttonnow)

        # Добавление виджетов:
        self.boxlayoutpopup.add_widget(labelwhat)
        self.boxlayoutpopup.add_widget(self.anchorlayoutpoputyes)
        self.boxlayoutpopup.add_widget(self.anchorlayoutpoputnow)

        # Кнопка возврата:
        back_button = Button(text="Back",
                             background_color=[5, 1, 1, 5],
                             size_hint_y=None, height=dp(55),
                             on_press=self._back_to_the_mainscreen)

        # Метка для обозначения что здесь хранятся кнопки:
        label_paswords = Label(text="Paswords:", font_size=25, size_hint_y=None, height=dp(30))

        # Добавляем виджети:
        self.layout.add_widget(back_button)
        self.layout.add_widget(label_paswords)

        # Создаем прокрутку:
        root = RecycleView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))

        root.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.add_widget(root)

        dic_foods = {b'a':b'b'}

        # Создаем цикл для создания кнопок:
        for f, d in sorted(dic_foods.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
            fd = f.decode('u8') + ' - ' + ''
            self.btn = Button(text=fd, size_hint_y=None, height=dp(70), on_press=self.delete_pasword)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)

    def on_leave(self):
        self.layout.clear_widgets()

    # Создаем диалоговое окно:
    def delete_pasword(self, arg):
        dlg = PopupClass(titleheader="Remove", message="Delete Pasword?",
                         options={"YES": "delete_func()", "NO": "now()"})

    # Здесь посути должны удалятся кнопки, но вылезает ошибка:
    def delete_func(self):
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.btn)

    # Функция для закрытия диалогового окна:
    def now(self):
        pass

    # Функция для возврата в главное меню:
    def _back_to_the_mainscreen(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "main_screen"


# Создаем класс для диалогового окна:
class PopupClass(SavePaswords):

    # Конструктор:
    def __init__(self, titleheader="Title", message="Message", options={"OK": "self.ok()", "NO": "self.no()"}):

        # Здесь ошибка:
        super(SavePaswords).__init__()

        def popup_active(event):
            self.retvalue = event.text
            self.delete.dismiss()

        self.retvalue = None
        self.options = options
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.box.add_widget(Label(text=message, font_size=20))
        b_list = []
        buttonbox = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        for b in options:
            b_list.append(Button(text=b, size_hint=(1, .35), font_size=20))
            b_list[-1].bind(on_press=popup_active)
            buttonbox.add_widget(b_list[-1])

        self.box.add_widget(buttonbox)
        self.delete = Popup(title=titleheader, content=self.box, size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300))
        self.delete.open()
        self.delete.bind(on_dismiss=self.on_close)

    def on_close(self, event):
        self.delete.unbind(on_dismiss=self.on_close)
        self.delete.dismiss()

        if self.retvalue:
            app.scrn.delete_func()


class SettingScreen(App):
    pass

class Screen(Widget):
    def btn_touch_up(self):
       SettingScreen().run()

class TouchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.scrn = SavePaswords()
        return self.scrn

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = TouchApp()
   app.run()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам ОГРОМНОЕ, знаю код говно, и мне сейчас даже за него стыдно, но это уже в прошлом. Вы очень выручили, и я вам очень благодарен особенно за старания

Comment: @Arteman Не, у вас так, норм. Это из-за микса моего с вашим и неполным пониманием обеих сторон ;). Только не забудьте доделать обе кнопки, если вы заметили, кнопка "нет" тоже удаляет, а то мне лень... ;)

Comment: Ок, это уже без проблем: ) Хорошего дня

Comment: @Arteman Разобрались зачен `self.scrn`?

Comment: Да, но в моем коде я сделал чуть по другому, так как использую ScreenManager, то я просто внутри PopupClass создал self.scrn = SavePaswords()

Comment: @Arteman ok....

Comment: Сначала кажется что все норм, и вы кстати все правильно сделали, но проблема в том, что без функции on_enter, не обойтись. К ней привязано сохранение, а с ней проблема уже с областью видимости.